# Many To Many in JPARepository Spring boot is not working properly

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, repository

Below you can see the two classes mapped many to many I'm using JPARepository to push the book to the database and I provided a JSON object in postman but the `authorList" seemed to be assigned to empty. I tried deleting the setter and getter but it is not working. my service method just calls the save method of the book nothing else. I want the cascade to take care of the rest but seems like it is not working very well. Anyone has any thoughts. Thanks

```
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long ISBN;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "bookList" , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Author> authorList = new HashSet<Author>();

    public Set<Author> getAuthorList() {
        return authorList;
    }

    public void setAuthorList(Set<Author> authorList) {
        this.authorList = authorList;
    }


@Entity
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="book_author",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "author_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "book_id") }
    )
    private Set<Book> bookList = new HashSet<Book>();

    public Set<Book> getBookList() {
        return bookList;
    }

    public void setBookList(Set<Book> bookList) {
        this.bookList = bookList;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
```

in `Author` class